# Ruby Elegant Way to Return Min/Max if Value Outside Range

Tags: ruby

So I am writing a program to model a process and need to calculate fees. The logic is that if the fee amount is less than a minimum use the minimum and if the fee amount is greater than the maximum use the maximum.

I can of course make this happen on multiple lines but would be interested to know if there is a more elegant way to do this in Ruby.

```
fee_amount = <whatever logic I need>
if fee_amount < min return min
if fee_amount > max return max
return fee_amount
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is just for one occasion, I would recommend Shawn Balestracci's answer, which is the most beautiful.

Alternatively, here are some methods from my personal library:

```
module Comparable
  def at_least other; self < other ? other : self end
  def at_most other; self > other ? other : self end
end
```

I use it like this:

```
fee_amount = <whatever logic I need>.at_least(min).at_most(max)
```

Comment: Unlike Shawn's, this is very clear and nice, I might add another `def bound_by range; self.at_least(range.first).at_most(range.last); end`

Comment: Why not just use `fee_amount.constrain!(min, max)` or the like, if you're going to consider "turn it into a function call" to be the same as making it a one-liner?

Comment: Sometimes, you just want to restrict only either min or max, so having these methods separately has more flexibility. And is more readable. Plus, if you have a method taking two arguments at a time, there is a chance that it becomes unclear which argument is which.

Answer (score 10):

If you're looking for a not so ugly (or at least short) one-liner:

```
[min,fee_amount,max].sort[1]
```

Definitely not Rubyish as it is not intuitive what is happening at first glance.

Comment: interesting approach for sure.

Comment: It's cute in a mongrel-dog way. :-)

Comment: It is the most elegant and the most beautiful.

Comment: It is _clever_, but _not beautiful_.  It is a very sidewise way to express the desired result and I would hope to never encounter it in production code unless it's the one line implementation of a method whose name tells me what it does.

Comment: @sawa There is nothing elegant or beautiful about throwing three items into an array and sorting it for the sake of squishing two lines into one. I can't imagine how *brutally* hard to maintain your code must be if you think this is actually a good idea.

Comment: You see this as "sidewise way" or "squishing two lines into one" only if you have in mind that "this ought to be written in two lines". But there is no basis for that. Why not start thinking with this code? What is wrong with "sort the three values and take the middle"? It is the most straightforward way. You can see similar things in various places. In some Olympic games, they take the scores from the referees, sort them, remove the min and the max, and take the average of the rest.

Answer (score 10):

Ruby 2.4 added [Comparable#clamp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp) that does exactly this

```
fee_amount.clamp(min, max)
```

https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/12/13/ruby-2-4-adds-comparable-clamp-method.html

Answer (score 4):

Use suffix conditionals, that'll be quite in ruby style.

```
return min if fee_amount < min
return max if fee_amount > max
fee_amount
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short one-liner:

```
 [[min, fee_amount].max, max].min
```

You should wrap this in a method with a descriptive name, my idea:

```
 def limit_by_range(value, min, max)
   [[min, value].max, max].min
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no *elegant* way of doing this in one line; you'd be making this *less* elegant by cramming that much logic into a single line of code.

Your existing code can be cleaned up substantially though:

```
fee_amount = <logic>
fee_amount = min if fee_amount < min
fee_amount = max if fee_amount > max
```

Versus this very ugly one-liner...

```
fee_amount = if fee_amount < min then min elsif fee_amount > max then max else fee_amount end
```

Comment: Agreed, doing it in one line is fugly. I've tried to do it, or similar things, too many times and now have learned that separate lines are sometimes much better than one. Structured ternary statements would be acceptable in C or Perl, but those aren't the Ruby way.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = (n <= max || n >= min) ? n : (n < min ? min : max)
```

a bit generic

Answer (score 0):

```
# stabby lambda function:
map = ->(val, min, max) { [min, val, max].sort[1] }

# call stabby function:
map.call(2.5, 1, 3)
=> 2.5
# or shorter:
map[2.5, 1, 3]
=> 2.5
```

Comment: Add some explanations to your answer.

Comment: sorry, this is my first STO post :)